# images not loading on wordpress website hosted on aws ec2

Tags: images, wordpress.com-hosting, wp-error

I have successfully deployed my wordpress website on AWS EC2 , directed to the custom domain, with SSL installed through load balancer and route 53 records

but now the images are not being shown in the website but earlier with ec2 domain address images were shown

how can i rectify it? i am new to the wordpress and aws

i have tried the go live plugin but no use

i want to make sure the website is secured with https and load images successfully and every other page

Comment: My experience with AWS (using Bitnami) was that the permissions for images regularly got cocked up - I genuinely don't know what the solution is but that may be a good place to start.